# How do I get confidence intervals around OLS estimate in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to estimate a simple OLS model using Python and I'm able to get the regression results, predicted values, but then it gives me the error:

> AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'

Here's the code I'm running - I read the documentation and the gist I found here at https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/1417e0473c2a87e14d76b425657342f5 and *think* I'm copying it correctly but I'm apparently doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


x = [51, 41, 52, 52, 43, 40, 50, 55, 53, 43]

y = [-13, -64, 34, -8, 3, -54, 7, 5, 27, -15]

mod = sm.OLS(y, x)

res = mod.fit()

print(res.summary())

predicted = res.predict()

pred = res.get_prediction() ## This line gives me the error
```

*Edit: Here's the full traceback*

```
AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1862-8a0a76dec686> in <module>()
----> 1 pred = res.get_prediction()
/Users/chadmurphy/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/base/wrapper.py in __getattribute__(self, attr)
     33             pass
     34 
---> 35         obj = getattr(results, attr)
     36         data = results.model.data
     37         how = self._wrap_attrs.get(attr)
AttributeError: 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'
>>>
```

Comment: Added to the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `statsmodels.api` but after looking at the gist i think the issue might be with your data. In the gist X and y are obtained with `intercept`

```
X = sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False) # add intercept
y = sort_data.loc[:,'Production']
```

Also error is stating `get_prediction` isn't there **after** you fit the model. Hope that puts you in the right direction.